# How should one read an LDAP distinguished name in simple english?

Tags: ldap

Say I have the following LDAP distinguished name:

```
CN=Payroll-Group,OU=Sales,OU=Eng,DC=Fabrikam,DC=COM
```

This DN features two OU's and two DC's. Why is this necessary and what exactly does it mean? Why is it necessary to include a DC "COM"? Wouldn't "Fabrikam" be good enough? And if you were to list two OUs, does that mean the CN must exist in each OU or just one of them?

TLDR: What would this DN read like if translated to simple English?

Comment: dns and rdns are explained here: https://ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns/

Comment: @digijay So if there are two OUs specified, does it look for the CN that exists in both OUs or just one?

Answer (score 2):

### Why are there two `DC`s?

By the definition in [RFC 4519, 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4519#section-2.4) a DNS domain name `example.com` must be split into two *labels* `example` and `com`; `DC=EXAMPLE,DC=COM` is just a way to present a hostname using `DomainComponent` attributes that dates back to [RFC 1279, 5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1279#section-5) from 1991.

### What is the meaning of two `OU`s?

The *Directory Information Tree* ([RFC 4512, 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.1)) is a **hierarchical structure**: in your example, the `CN=Payroll-Group` is in `OU=Sales` which itself is in `OU=Eng`. Both `OU`s are listed in the LDAP *distinguished name*, because by definition it must be a *fully qualified name*:

> **[2.3.2.  Distinguished Names](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.3.2)**
>
> An entry's fully qualified name, known as its Distinguished Name
> (DN) [[X.501](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#ref-X.501)], is the concatenation of its RDN and its immediate
> superior's    DN.  A Distinguished Name unambiguously refers to an
> entry in the    tree.  The following are examples of string
> representations of DNs [[RFC4514](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4514)]:
>
> ```
>   UID=nobody@example.com,DC=example,DC=com
>
>   CN=John Smith,OU=Sales,O=ACME Limited,L=Moab,ST=Utah,C=US
> ```

### A simple illustration

In simple English **the Payroll-Group is part of Sales under Eng in domain `fabricam.com`**. The `CN=Payroll-Group` is in `OU=Sales`. It's not directly in `OU=Eng`, but is a member of `OU=Eng` through the `OU=Sales`. A Directory Information Tree diagram may help in comprehending this:

[image]